# C++\Cli COM assembly cannot be registered by MSI

Tags: com, c++-cli, windows-installer

I have a serious problem with my application. I have a native application that uses some managed classes to work. I have created a C++\Cli wrapper that is a proxy between unmanaged and managed code.

In this proxy project I have declared some COM objects that are exposed and their implementation uses C# objects declared in managed assembly.

Everything works fine on my dev environment, but problem appears when I want to install my application on clean system.

I have a MSI project that shoul register this CLR proxy using **vsdraCOM** or **vsdraCOMRelativePath**. In fact none of them does not work. Application shows error that particular object (defined in this proxy) is not registered.

I am able to register this dll manually using regsvr32, but I want to avoid this and let my MSI package do it for me.

I have tried using Regasm on this dll and it says that no object was found for registration. All of exposed interfaces are defined in **IDL** file.

Can you tell me how to make these IDL defined interfaces to be exposed or visible to regasm?

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to register this dll manually using regsvr32, but I want to
>   avoid this and let my MSI package do it for me.

The registration options offered by Visual Studio are for general use. If they don't work for you, then you need to determine how your files need to be registered and use a custom action to do it.

If using regsvr32.exe works, use it in custom actions which register your files.

> I have tried using Regasm on this dll and it says that no object was
>   found for registration.

[Regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28VS.71%29.aspx?ppud=4) is not the same as [regsvr32.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regsvr32.mspx?mfr=true). Regasm.exe registers assemblies and regsv32.exe registers command components.

> Can you tell me how to make these IDL defined interfaces to be exposed
>   or visible to regasm?

Regasm.exe can register only strong-named assemblies. You can read more about this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwb8f617.aspx